# The "right" way to make an element fill a jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've got a bootstrap.js Jumbotron with a multi-Select Element in it. By default the element is just big enough to fit the largest string (naturally). I'd like it to stretch across the Jumbotron's width. I can do this with custom CSS, but it feels like I should be using the built in features of bootstrap to do it instead of writing my own CS here.

I'm a bootstrap newbie so all I knew to try was the column features which don't seem to work inside a Jumbotron. Am I doing something wrong/silly/pointless by writing my own CSS to achieve the effect? i.e. is there a better way? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Sure, sorry, shoulda had a jsfiddle ready. Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/eve6q969/

The relevant part is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h3>My Items</h3>

        <form>
        <div class="form-group">
        <select id="ItemsSelect" size="10" multiple>
            <option >Item # 1</option>
            <option >Item # 2</option>
            <option >Item # 3</option>
        <select>
        </div>
        </form>

        <a href="#newItem" class = "btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">New Item</a>
        <a href="#" class = "btn btn-info">Edit Item</a>
        <a href="#" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete Item</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Selector is only as big as it needs to be to fit the "Item 1" text, but I'd like it to span the Jumbotron (minus left/right margin space).

Naturally Serg's suggestion works like a charm :)

```
            <select class="full-width" id="mapsSelect" size="10" multiple>
                <option >Map # 1</option>
                <option >Map # 2</option>
                <option >Map # 3</option>
            <select>
```

with the line

```
.full-width{width: 100%;}
```

added to my css file. But I was wondering if I'm doing the 'right' thing by using it.

UPDATE:

Thanks Teison, you're correct. All I needed was the `form-control` class. Like so:

```
            <form>
            <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="mapsSelect" size="10" multiple>
                <option >Map # 1</option>
                <option >Map # 2</option>
                <option >Map # 3</option>
            <select>
            </div>
            </form>
```

I'd thought I'd tried this but my sleep addled brain must have some something stupid.

Thanks!

Comment: Create a **live** working example (jsfiddle/codepen/snippet). No one can really understand what exactly is the problem form reading this text.

Comment: Can you create a small jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue and to set up a base for an answer?

Comment: This is a popular issue for bootstrap, there's nothing wrong with writing your own class. Just add something like .full-width{width: 100%;} and use that

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: The `form-control` class already makes an input or select full-width. Is there a reason you're not using it?

Comment: does it feel "right" to you?

Answer (score 0):

So yes, using the form-control class is the right answer. "Right" in the sense that I'm using bootstrap.js to do my formatting & css instead of doing it myself (which would sort of defeat the purpose of using bootstrap.js). Here's what it looks like:

https://jsfiddle.net/2v9pqfrk/2/

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">   
 <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Items</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Items <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#newItem" data-toggle="modal">New Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Edit Item</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Import Items</a></li>
                </ul>                   
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h3>My Items</h3>

            <form>
            <div class="form-group">
            <select id="ItemsSelect" size="10" multiple class="form-control">
                <option >Item # 1</option>
                <option >Item # 2</option>
                <option >Item # 3</option>
            <select>
            </div>
            </form>

            <a href="#newItem" class = "btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">New Item</a>
            <a href="#" class = "btn btn-info">Edit Item</a>
            <a href="#" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete Item</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">              
                <h3><a class="btn btn-info" href="#">Import Items</a></h3>
                <p>Click here import Items with selected Item</p>               
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">              
                <h3><a class="btn btn-info" href="#">Item Upload</a></h3>
                <p>Click here to log in and upload items</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom >
        <div class="container">
            <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Items</p>

        </div>
    <div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="newItem" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header"><h4>New Item</h4></div>
                <div class="modal-body"><p>New Item</p></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <body>
```